# asp.net c# Subscribe to the next Page.Load event from function

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, delegates

We need to subscribe to the next page load event from a function inside our library

The problem is that the only place where the subscribe works is if we do it in the Page.OnInit like this:

```
override protected void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack){
            this.Load += test; //this would work only the first time if you want the test function to be called in each pageload you have to remove the !ispostback condition
    }

protected void test(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {//enters correctly

    }
```

What we want is this:

```
In website proyect:

    buttonDoSomething_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Functions.CheckNextPageLoad(this);
    }

In function library proyect:

    CheckNextPageLoad(Page pagex)
    {
        pagex.Load+=CheckNextPageLoadEvent;
    }

CheckNextPageLoadEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Page page = HttpContext.Current.Handler as Page; //or get it from the sender object

   //check especific property of the postback or change something especific

}
```

This would be helpful as an alternative solution to a related question of ours (so 2x1): 
[ASP.NET c# Fix for the OK event of a custom ConfirmMessagebox inside a function library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10894116/asp-net-c-sharp-fix-for-the-ok-event-of-a-custom-confirmmessagebox-inside-a-func)
(Getting the button clicked on the postback/next pageload we could call the delegate method)

Comment: Could a HttpHandler be useful? http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308001

Comment: So if my understanding is correct, if someone clicks a button you want somehow _remember_ in your code that _all_ the next postbacks will execute an additional handler for the `Page.Load` event??? Is this the behavior you are looking for?

Comment: @Jupaol The logic would be that we show a confirmation message (passing in addition to the confirmmessage function a delegate function to be called if the user clicks 'yes' button) generated throught javascript and register for the NEXT(only) pageload event, the user clicks the yes button, our custom pageload event is triggered, inside we check the clicked button is the 'yes' one, if thats so we call the delegated function...simple alas complex...

Comment: @AmiramKorach doesnt seem to be the case but if you could present a solution inside our question context that works with httphandler we would be thankful